# XPATH identifier from HTML

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
<ul class="popupmenu is-open" id="menuFormDefaultFC" role="menu" aria-hidden="false">
<li role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem" href="#A">Add</a>
```

Please somebody let me know the Xpath for above html with href in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options for href.

```
1. By.xpath(".//a[@href='#A']");
2. By.xpath(".//li[@role='presentation']/a[@href='#A']");
```

But for links you could use just `linkText`. I prefer below for simplicity unless your app supports multiple locales.

```
By.linkText("Add");
```

Or use CSS selectors

```
1. By.cssSelector("a[role='presentation']");
2. By.cssSelector("li[role='presentation']>a[href='#A']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `//a[contains(text(),'Add')]`

It may be used as `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Add')]")`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
By closedMenu = By.xpath(".//ul[not(contains(@class, 'is-open'))]");
By openMenu = By.xpath(".//ul[contains(@class, 'is-open')]");
By addItem = By.linkText("Add");
By addItemLocator = new ByChained(openMenu, addItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox plugin "Firepath" to extract xpath.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firepath/